# Why kubernetes' statefulset didn't run evenly for 3 pods?

Tags: kubernetes, logstash, load-balancing, filebeat, kubernetes-statefulset

I deployed a logstash by statefulset kind with 3 replicas in k8s. Using filebeat to send data to it.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: logstash-nginx
spec:
  serviceName: "logstash"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: logstash
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logstash
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: logstash
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.10.0
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 2Gi
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5044
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config
          - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
        args:
          - bin/logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf;
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: logstash-configmap
            items:
              - key: logstash.yml
                path: logstash.yml
        - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
          configMap:
            name: logstash-configmap
            items:
              - key: logstash.conf
                path: logstash.conf
```

Logstash's service

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: logstash
  name: logstash
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "5044"
      port: 5044
      targetPort: 5044
  selector:
    app: logstash
```

Filebeat's daemonset configmap

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    ...

    output.logstash:
      hosts: ["logstash.default.svc.cluster.local:5044"]
      loadbalance: true
      bulk_max_size: 1024
```

When run real data. Most data went to the second logstash's pod. Sometimes data also can go to the first and the third pods but very little occurs.

---

Use another way to set LB from filebeat

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    ...

    output.logstash:
      hosts: ["logstash-nginx-0.logstash.default.svc.cluster.local:5044", "logstash-nginx-1.logstash.default.svc.cluster.local:5044", "logstash-nginx-2.logstash.default.svc.cluster.local:5044"]
      loadbalance: true
      bulk_max_size: 1024
```

Logstash's configmap

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-configmap
data:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
    xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
```

From the filebeat pod, it can access URIs by `curl`:

- logstash-nginx-0.logstash.default.svc.cluster.local:5044
- logstash-nginx-1.logstash.default.svc.cluster.local:5044
- logstash-nginx-2.logstash.default.svc.cluster.local:5044

But the data can't be sent by filebeat to logstash's 3 pods at all. No traffic in the logstash's output logs. Where is wrong?

Comment: What GKE version are you using. Can you check pod logs and verify if there is something suspicious in logs?

Comment: Do you need 3 replicas? I saw that you are using `sts` with `selectors`. As per [sts limitations docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#limitations) `StatefulSets currently require a Headless Service to be responsible for the network identity of the Pods. You are responsible for creating this Service.` Filebeat provides configuration options that you can use to fine tune load balancing when sending events to [multiple hosts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.8/load-balancing.html).

Comment: You can try to set-up output logstash with [Stable Network ID](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id) for stst pods. `The domain managed by this Service takes the form: $(service name).$(namespace).svc.cluster.local, where "cluster.local" is the cluster domain.` It would look like: `logstash-nginx-0.logstash.default.svc.cluster.local, logstash-nginx-1.logstash.default.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: @PjoterS Thank you for your advice. I tried your method. It seems should work but can't run. I posted the information to the end of the question.